# Move ZFS filesystem (including snapshots) from one pool to another

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, zfsonlinux

I work with a setup where we use ZFS snapshots to maintain a historical record. We have a need to migrate this data from one ZFS pool to another.

This question ([Moving a ZFS filesystem from one pool to another](https://serverfault.com/questions/88638/moving-a-zfs-filesystem-from-one-pool-to-another)) appears to be almost what I need. However, in my case I would like to move all of the snapshots, not just current data.

Anyone know how this would be done?

For reference, this is using zfs-fuse on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you *sure* you're using zfs-fuse and not the real ZFS-on-Linux?

Either way, you would use `zfs send` to move a filesystem. Be sure to use the `-R` option:

```
   -R

       Generate a replication stream package, which will replicate the specified filesystem, and all
       descendent  file systems, up to the named snapshot. When received, all properties, snapshots,
       descendent file systems, and clones are preserved.
```

Comment: I installed the zfs-fuse package and have a zfs-fuse process taking a good portion of CPU during rsync jobs.

Should I be using the real ZFS-on-linux?

Comment: Looks like the -R option is what I was missing. I will go test it now.

Comment: Yes, you should be using [ZFS-on-Linux](http://zfsonlinux.org) these days.